# Integration of Wordpress with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

We are working with a client who has an inventory system using asp.net.

We are developing his ecommerce solution within Wordpress and this needs to be updated by the asp.net inventory system ?

Ideas on how this can be integrated would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by integration? If you only need to share the database, you could use the [PDO for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdo-for-wordpress/) plugin to connect to the MSSQL db.

Answer (score 0):

If sharing DBs isn't an option, I would turn to web services to synchronize the data between the systems.